# The Geolocation service failed - error

Tags: linux, geolocation

I have Linux Mint OS and I need to make a project.
I use the geolocation service to get the current location of the user.

Since yesterday I get `The Geolocation service failed` error message.

It was the same problem on my laptop as well but it works now.

If I open the Google API's page then I still have the same problem.

[image]

I tried to use different wifi to access the web (mobile hot spot), changed the DNS server and I still have this problem.

I asked different people to pull my repo and it works just fine for them.
I host my project on GitHub and it works for everyone apart from me.

I tried to use Linux from USB stick as Live session and the problem is still exist.

What else I should try?

Thank you